# How to check connection to DB without having the db its tables names

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

The point here is that I **don't have** the data base table names so please don't suggest to choose one table on to do on it 'SELECT COUNT(*)'

Comment: If you don't know the db table names, what do you need to check a connection for?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes - I want to create a generic Base Class that manage my connection to the DB. I give it the connection string but to give it a table name just for checking the connection seems exaggerated to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the database, but usually there are some tables that always exist or a table isn't even required.

For Oracle:

```
SELECT 1 FROM dual
```

For SqlServer:

```
SELECT 1
```

Not very elegant, but generally does the job if you know the database brand.

Comment: I disagree with "not very elegant". Ok, the Oracle version is ugly, but that's because of the hack that is `dual`. But `SELECT 1` is extremely elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what database type it is, but you could use something like [`DbConnection.GetSchema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s98te64s.aspx) which is bound to need a working connection. I don't know how heavy a hit that would be though... if you knew more about the database type there may be a simpler "heartbeat" query you could perform.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a command that doesn't query against a table, such as:

```
select @@VERSION
```